# How to use sparse matrix if the matrix is too big to be allocated

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have code for a diagonal/sparse matrix like

```
nx=50
ny=50
nz=50

num1=123
num2=345
dig1=np.diag([num1]*nx*ny*nz)
dig2=mp.diag([num2]*(nx*ny*nz-nx*ny),nx*ny)
out=dig1+dig2
```

However, it is unable to allocate 116.GiB, so I think it is better to use a sparse matrix, but how can I use

```
csrout=csr_matrix(out)
```

before it allocate the memory

Comment: Running your code gives a `ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d.`  from `dig1=np.diag(num1*nx*ny*nz)`

Comment: You have to construct the `csr` matrix directly.  The `coo` style of inputs are usually the easiest to understand.  But there are also a couple of sparse functions for making the matrix from diagonals.   Experiment with small dimensions before risking memory errors with big ones.